# Change style of android MediaController

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there a way to customize the MediaController? I need to change the style of buttons, SeekBar etc.

Comment: Here is an example MediaController customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `makeControllerView` was meant to be overridden so you could supply your own view. Unfortunately, it is hidden at the moment.

You may want to take the source of MediaController and either reimplement it or copy-and-paste the hidden methods into a subclass so you can customize it.

Comment: `makeControllerView` is `protected` for the source I'm looking at. Does anybody know when it changed from `private` to `protected`?

Comment: Oh, perhaps you are talking about the @hide in the javadoc for the `makeControllerView` in `android.widget.MediaController`.  While this javadoc bit appears to stop the `@Override` annotation from working, it does *not* actually prevent overriding the method.  Original question stands almost unchanged - was this ever private?

Answer (score 8):

What you can do is recurse the view hierarchy of your MediaController and set the SeekBar's drawable programmatically:

```
private void styleMediaController(View view) {
    if (view instanceof MediaController) {
        MediaController v = (MediaController) view;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
            styleMediaController(v.getChildAt(i));
        }
    } else
        if (view instanceof LinearLayout) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
            for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                styleMediaController(ll.getChildAt(i));
            }
        } else if (view instanceof SeekBar) {
            ((SeekBar) view).setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar)); 
            ((SeekBar) view).setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progresshandle));
        }
}
```

Then, just call

```
styleMediaController(myMC);
```

Comment: Your code does not work for me. What is the reason for the paremeter `index`? `v.getChildCount()` returns 0 everytime.

Comment: @rekire The index parameter is needed because the function gets called recursively by itself, descending the view hierarchy of the MediaController view.

Comment: But the variable `index` is never used.

Comment: @rekire It is, see line 5 and 11 of the above snippet ;-)

Comment: Which has some point to it ;-) Edited the post to remove the superfluous argument, thanks!

Comment: Had to call `styleMediaController(myMC)` in the `OnPreparedListener` of the `VideoView` to make it work. Otherwise the MediaController view has no children.

Comment: That really is a terrible solution in terms of almost everything (readability, stability etc.). Yet it seems that framework has left us with no choice. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

I changed the code of bk138's answer **to just change the color** of the elements. Not the drawables themselves. This solution is compatible to old devices in conjunction with the support library v4.

```
private void styleMediaController(View view) {
        if (view instanceof MediaController) {
            MediaController v = (MediaController) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
                styleMediaController(v.getChildAt(i));
            }
        } else if (view instanceof LinearLayout) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                styleMediaController(ll.getChildAt(i));
            }
        } else if (view instanceof SeekBar) {
            ((SeekBar) view)
                    .getProgressDrawable()
                    .mutate()
                    .setColorFilter(
                            getResources().getColor(
                                    R.color.MediaPlayerMeterColor),
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            Drawable thumb = ((SeekBar) view).getThumb().mutate();
            if (thumb instanceof android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper) {
                //compat mode, requires support library v4
                ((android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper) thumb).setCompatTint(getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.MediaPlayerThumbColor));
            } else {
                //lollipop devices
                thumb.setColorFilter(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.MediaPlayerThumbColor),
                        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, just call

```
styleMediaController(myMC);
```

Had to call `styleMediaController(myMC)` in the `OnPreparedListener` of the `VideoView` to make it work. Otherwise the MediaController view has no children.

Comment: what is `setCompatTint`?