# Android It is possible to change the MediaController graphics?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview, android-video-player

I want to create a custom video player, so i want to change the mediacontroller ?

I looked over the following posts, but i haven't seen an answer:

[Extending MediaController for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881272/extending-mediacontroller-for-android)

[Change style of android MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044000/change-style-of-android-mediacontroller)

Comment: Here is an example MediaController customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144